# Why am I getting a runtime error when using printf?

Tags: java

When trying to print info from my Account class, it comes up with an error.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.printf("%5d $,9.2f %,5,2f%% %29s\n\n", account1.getId(), account1.getBalance(), account1.getAnnualInterestRate(), account1.getDateCreated());
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ','
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at TestAccount.printAccount(TestAccount.java:16)
    at TestAccount.main(TestAccount.java:11)
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be complaining about a comma.

Comment: Maybe try "%5d $,9.2f %,5.2f%% %29s\n\n"?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `%,5,2f`?

Comment: It was all typos. Thanks guys! Sorry for the waste of a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("%5d$, %9.2f, %5.2f, %29s\n\n", ...);
```

Which will print:

- An integer padded to at least 5 spaces for the first argument
- A float padded at least 9 spaces before the radix and has 2 digits after for the second argument
- A float padded at least 5 spaces before the radix and has 2 digits after for the third argument
- A string padded to at least 29 characters for the forth argument

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid conversion string:

```
%,5,2f
```

is not a valid conversion specifier. (Did you mean `%5.2f` ?)

Comment: That's it. This was for a university assignment, and I was given the format string. I guess I didn't see that when I copy/pasted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have `%,5,2f%%` in your formatter which I think should be `%,5.2f%%`

Also, you might want to use `$%,9.2f` instead of `$,9.2f`

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is *malformed* as IntelliJ shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you have putted the "%" after 9.2f (like 9.2f %), I think your intension is to get  the account balance so put the "%" before 9.2f (like %9.2f). Below is the corrected argument which works for me.

System.out.printf("%5d $,%9.2f,5,%2f%% %29s",account1.getId(), account1.getBalance(), account1.getAnnualInterestRate(), account1.getDateCreated());